# How to Evaluate Func<T, bool> with use EF.Functions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, roslyn, func, csharpscript

I'm trying to evaluate `func<T, bool>` with `EF.Functions.Like` in `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync`, But I have an error in run time (The name 'EF' does not exist in the current context) when call `GetPredicate()` method.

Create Func Method:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static async Task<Func<T, bool>> GetPredicate<T>(string stringExpression)
            {
                ScriptOptions options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(references: typeof(T).Assembly);
                Func<T, bool> discountFilterExpression = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<T, bool>>(stringExpression, options);

                return discountFilterExpression;
            }
}
```

Call Method:

```
string expString = "x => EF.Functions.Like(x.CodeId, pattern) || EF.Functions.Like(x.Name, pattern) || EF.Functions.Like(x.CategoryId, pattern)";
Func<MyClass, bool> exp = await Helper.GetPredicate<MyClass>(expString);
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EF.Functions` usually are not supposed to be evaluated.

But to answer your concrete question, you need to add both *reference* to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` *assembly* and *import* (`using`) of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` *namespace*, e.g.

```
ScriptOptions options = ScriptOptions.Default
    .AddReferences(references: typeof(T).Assembly)
    .AddReferences(typeof(EF).Assembly) // <--
    .AddImports(typeof(EF).Namespace); // <--
```